# Armadillo C++: Passing a submatrix into a function

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using C++ and the Armadillo library. I have a function of the form

```
arma::mat foo(arma::mat my_matrix)
```

I want to pass a submatrix of `my_matrix` to `foo`.
Submatrices can be extracted like this:

```
my_matrix.col(0)
```

But whenever I try to do this:

```
foo(my_matrix.col(0))
```

I get a compilation error. **How can I fix it without having to do this**:

```
mat submatrix = my_matrix.col(0)
foo(submatrix)
```

(which does indeed work, but involves an extra line of code).

Comment: Look into what type 'col'  returns. It's probably a type that isn't a matrix, but can be used by the array constructor to initialize it.

Comment: Did you mean to write a function with signature `foo(arma::mat&)` (a reference as argument). Because the situation you describe with `foo(arma::mat)` works without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the input type to a const reference (`const arma::mat&`), which allows the compiler to automatically generate a temporary matrix in such cases.

Example:

```
using namespace arma;

mat foo(const mat& my_matrix)
{
  mat y = my_matrix * 2.0;

  return y;
}


void bar()
{
  mat x(10,10, fill::randu);

  mat y = foo( x.col(0) );

  y.print("y:");
}
```